# Getting response headers for a get request in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am trying to do a get request using basic auth and need to fetch the token from the response headers. I've gone through similar questions and am doing what was suggested there however I'm still not able to get the required header. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my code:

```
testLogin(): Observable < any > {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')
    }),
    observe: 'response'
    as 'body'
  };
  return this.http.get < any[] > ('/login', httpOptions);
}

...

this.service.testLogin().subscribe(r => {
  console.log(r.headers);
});
```

The following is printed on the console:

```
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
lazyInit: () => {…}
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0)
[[Entries]]
No properties
size: (...)
__proto__: Map
__proto__:
append: ƒ append(name, value)
applyUpdate: applyUpdate(update) { const key = update.name.toLowerCase(); switch (update.op) { case 'a': case 's': let value = update.value; if (typeof value === 'string') { value = [value]; } if (value.length === 0) { return; } this.maybeSetNormalizedName(update.name, key); const base = (update.op === 'a' ? this.headers.get(key) : undefined) || []; base.push(...value); this.headers.set(key, base); break; case 'd': const toDelete = update.value; if (!toDelete) { this.headers.delete(key); this.normalizedNames.delete(key); } else { let existing = this.headers.get(key); if (!existing) { return; } existing = existing.filter(value => {…}
clone: ƒ clone(update)
constructor: class HttpHeaders
copyFrom: copyFrom(other) { other.init(); Array.from(other.headers.keys()).forEach(key => {…}
delete: ƒ delete(name, value)
forEach: forEach(fn) { this.init(); Array.from(this.normalizedNames.keys()) .forEach(key => {…}
get: ƒ get(name)
getAll: ƒ getAll(name)
has: ƒ has(name)
init: init() { if (!!this.lazyInit) { if (this.lazyInit instanceof HttpHeaders) { this.copyFrom(this.lazyInit); } else { this.lazyInit(); } this.lazyInit = null; if (!!this.lazyUpdate) { this.lazyUpdate.forEach(update => {…}
keys: ƒ keys()
maybeSetNormalizedName: ƒ maybeSetNormalizedName(name, lcName)
set: ƒ set(name, value)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Are you requesting a different domain than the one your application runs on? In this case it‘s probably due to CORS that you can‘t access the headers on the client application.

Comment: I am using proxy-config. Wouldn't that take care of CORS? Also as of now both the client and server are running on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `observe` to response:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("username:password")
  }),
  observe: "response"
};
```

Plus, I don't think you can read all the response headers.

You can check the ones that you can read by using the **[`response.headers.keys()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#keys)** method.

```
this.service.testLogin().subscribe(response => {
  response.headers
    .keys()
    .forEach(keyName =>
      console.log(
        `The value of the ${keyName} header is: ${response.headers.get(
              keyName
            )}`
      )
    );
});
```

> Here's a working [Sample Code on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-response-headers-in-angular?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

Have you exposed the token from server-side? In your console log, there is no token I have seen. If there is a token then you can access it as like `r.headers.get('token_name')`. If you don't expose it from the server-side please see this problem. I may think the first two solutions can help you.

Comment: yeah I wasn't doing the get call, I'm able to access the token now.